# How to get vertical gap between images in a flex container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```
<div class='parent'>
<img class='child' src='...' alt='img'>
<img class='child' src='...' alt='img'>
<img class='child' src='...' alt='img'>
<img class='child' src='...' alt='img'>
<img class='child' src='...' alt='img'>
<img class='child' src='...' alt='img'>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.parent{
display:flex;
flex-wrap:wrap;
justify-content:space-between;
align-content: space-between;
}

.child{
display:block;
width:calc(25% - 10px);
margin:0 auto;
}
```

Images have horizontal gap 10px, but there is no vertical gap (distance between images in a column.

How to add this gap without having padding/margin between `childs` and `parent`. I need only gaps between images but in both directions.

Also, images have no fixed width and height.

Comment: Just give the images `margin-bottom:10px?`

Comment: or max-width:25% + padding:5px + mind box-sizing... there's many ways. Are each image of the same ratio ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be a use case of CSS-grid instead of flexbox:

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px; /*define the distance between elements*/
  border: 1px solid;
}

.child{
  height:50px;
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: not too sure about op's ratio image in real. object-fit might also be a clue ;)

Comment: @G-Cyr yes, but I am suspecting they have the same ratio since they need to have the same gap horizontally and vertically ;)

Comment: I was not too sure from the last line of the question ;)

Answer (score -1):

Only a simple

```
.parent{

    display: flex;
    gap: 5em;(You can give any size)
}
```

Should work considering the images are in appropriate size. Try reducing the image size and do it again.